# Find the limit of a given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$, with $x_0 = 1$ and $x_{n + 1} = x_n + \ln{(x_n^2 + 1)}$, $\forall n \geq 0$.

All I know is that $(x_n)$ is increasing. I found this by calculating $x_{n + 1} - x_n = \ln{(x_n^2 + 1)}$ which is greater than $0$.

Now, all I need is finding an upper bound for $(x_n)$, and then I can easily calculate its limit. But I don't know how to find it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why should it have an upper bound?  $\ln {(x_n^2+1)}≥1$, at least for $n≥3$ so your sequence goes up by at least $1$ at each stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current initial value, there is no upper bound. Since we have $x_{n} \geq x_0=1$ for all $n$. If $x_n$ is bounded above, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x \geq x_0 = 1$ exists and $x = x + \ln(x^2+1)$ so $x^2 = 0$ i,e., $x=0$ which contradicts $x \geq 1.$

Since the limit, if it exists must be $0$ and $x_n$ increases we can hope for convergence only if $x_0 \leq 0.$

So consider if you had $ -1 < x_0 < 0 $ instead of $x_0 =1$. Then we would still have $x_{n+1} \geq x_n$, and since  $\ln(1+x^2) \leq x^2$ for all $x$. we would also have $x_{n+1} \leq x_n + x_n^2 = x_n ( x_n + 1).$ Note that if $-1 \leq x_n \leq 0$ then $x_{n+1} \geq x_n \geq -1$ and $x_{n+1} \leq x_n ( 1 + x_n) \leq 0$  so it inductively follows that $ -1 \leq x_n \leq 0$ for all $n$. And from this it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0.$